# How to enable coloring text on Sublime

Tags: sublimetext, cpu-word

I downloaded an install Sublime editor. I want to color the text when writing in specific programming languages, so that I can copy/Paste to Word. I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7Gv77BkTlE but nothing worked on me. Does anyone know how do I enable text coloring on Sublime? Otherwise is there any other editor that I can use in order  to get colored text so that I can Copy/Paste it to Word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasting from VSCode to word keeps the formatting and colors for me. You do have to make sure you paste with source formatting.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that there is an option at the bottom right of the Sublime Text to select the programming language. The menu to select other languages opens up when you click on it (C++ on the screenshot). This is on version 4143

[image: Image that shows the option to change the color coding for a specific programming language is.]